# Xamarin jar binding for Exact Target Journey Builder Android SDK

Tags: android, binding, jar, xamarin, exacttarget

Has anyone successfully bound the Exact Target Journey Builder Android SDK? I can bind most of it successfully, but get stuck on this error message:

> missing class error was raised while reflecting 
>       com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETLocationManager : 
>       com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks

I've included all the Xamarin Google Play Services NuGet packages, but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: `GooglePlayServicesClient` has been replaced by `GoogleApiClient`, are you using the latest version, i.e. `etsdk-4.1.0.jar`

Comment: Please ask SF or SFMC related questions on [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com)